# Jest TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I tried to figure out why the test failed for the article.controller.js file. But, unable to find the cause of it.

[file:article.controller.js]

```js
const {
  saveArticle
} = require('../services/article.service');

exports.createArticle = async (req, res, next) => {
  saveArticle(req.user._id, req.body.article)
    .then((savedArticle) => {
      if (savedArticle) {
        return res.status(200).json({ article: savedArticle });
      }
    })
    .catch(next);
};
```

[file:article.controller.test.js]

```js
const { createArticle } = require("../../../controllers/article.controller");
var { saveArticle } = require("../../../services/article.service");
const articleServiceHelper = require("../../../services/article.service");

const mockRequest = () => {
  return {
    title: "Sample article title",
    description: "Sample article description",
    body: "Sample article body"
  };
};

const mockResponse = () => {
  return {
    status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    json: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
  };
};

const mockNext = jest.fn();

const mockUser = {
  _id: "6368ad4347dkhs"
}

const mockArticle = {
  title: "Sample article title",
  description: "Sample article description",
  body: "Sample article body"
}

describe("Unit tests for article.controller.js file", () => {
  describe("createArticle tests", () => {
    test("If user can create an article", async () => {
      //Arrange
      let mockReq = mockArticle;
      mockReq = { ...mockReq, _id: "6368ad4347dkhs" };
      const mockRes = mockResponse();
      const saveArticleSpy = jest.spyOn(articleServiceHelper, "saveArticle").mockResolvedValue({ article: mockArticle });
      //Act
      await createArticle(mockReq, mockRes, mockNext);
      //Assert
      expect(saveArticleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(saveArticleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockUser._id, mockArticle);
      expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
      expect(mockRes.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        article: mockArticle
      });
      expect(mockNext).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

[Output]

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')

```
  12 |
  13 | exports.createArticle = async (req, res, next) => {
> 14 |   saveArticle(req.user._id, req.body.article)
     |                        ^
  15 |     .then((savedArticle) => {
  16 |       if (savedArticle) {
  17 |         return res.status(200).json({ article: savedArticle });

  at Object.<anonymous>.exports.createArticle (controllers/article.controller.js:14:24)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/unit/controllers/article.controller.test.js:41:13)
```

I wanted to simply test **createArticle** function. It's happy and edge case scenarios.

Comment: You missing the user property in `mockReq` object: probably should be `mockReq = { ...mockReq, ...{user: {_id: "6368ad4347dkhs" }}};` instead of `mockReq = { ...mockReq, _id: "6368ad4347dkhs" };`

Comment: @TBA I did the changes accordingly. Now, I am getting different error. 

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some issues:

1. The `mockReq` is not correct, it should be:

```js
const mockReq = { user: { _id: '6368ad4347dkhs' }, body: { article: mockArticle } }
```

2. The `./article.controller` module should be required after `jest.spyOn(articleServiceHelper, 'saveArticle')` so that the `saveArticle()` function is spied. If you require the `./article.controller` module before `jest.spyOn()`, the deconstructed `saveArticle()` function is **not** spied.
3. The mock resolved value of `articleServiceHelper.saveArticle()` should be `mockArticle` rather than `{ article: mockArticle }` according to the assertion.
4. The `createArticle()` function should return the promise returned by `saveArticle()` so that you can use `await createArticle()`.
5. The test case is going to test "user can create an article", so the `mockNext()` function will **not** be called. The assertion should be `expect(mockNext).not.toHaveBeenCalled()`.

So the complete working example is:

`article.service.js`:

```js
exports.saveArticle = async (id, article) => {
  throw new Error('Not implemented');
};
```

`article.controller.js`:

```js
const { saveArticle } = require('./article.service');

exports.createArticle = (req, res, next) => {
  return saveArticle(req.user._id, req.body.article)
    .then((savedArticle) => {
      if (savedArticle) {
        return res.status(200).json({ article: savedArticle });
      }
    })
    .catch(next);
};
```

`article.controller.test.js`:

```js
const articleServiceHelper = require('./article.service');

const mockResponse = () => {
  return {
    status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    json: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  };
};

const mockNext = jest.fn();

const mockUser = {
  _id: '6368ad4347dkhs',
};

const mockArticle = {
  title: 'Sample article title',
  description: 'Sample article description',
  body: 'Sample article body',
};

describe('Unit tests for article.controller.js file', () => {
  describe('createArticle tests', () => {
    test('If user can create an article', async () => {
      //Arrange
      const mockReq = { user: { _id: '6368ad4347dkhs' }, body: { article: mockArticle } };
      const mockRes = mockResponse();
      const saveArticleSpy = jest.spyOn(articleServiceHelper, 'saveArticle').mockResolvedValue(mockArticle);
      const { createArticle } = require('./article.controller');
      //Act
      await createArticle(mockReq, mockRes, mockNext);
      //Assert
      expect(saveArticleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(saveArticleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockUser._id, mockArticle);
      expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
      expect(mockRes.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ article: mockArticle });
      expect(mockNext).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/78011736/article.controller.test.js                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  Unit tests for article.controller.js file
    createArticle tests                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      √ If user can create an article (33 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------                                                                                                                                                                              
File                   | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s                                                                                                                                                                               
-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files              |   85.71 |       50 |   66.66 |   85.71 | 
 article.controller.js |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 6
 article.service.js    |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 2
-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.12 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```